# Cambiar valor de "content" en un selector ":before"

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer un span que cuando hagas clic se despliegue una capa con un mensaje y que se haga un cambio de icono cuando se despliegue.
Para ello tengo una "X" como content que he puesto en el ":before" de dicho span y queda muy bien, pero ¿Como puedo Cambiar valor de dicho "content" en el selector ":before" para que muestre una "V" una vez se despliegue la capa?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => 
    {
        const varAux_cadComparar = e.target.id;
        switch(true){
            case (/^elemSpan/).test(varAux_cadComparar):{
                fun_cambiarIconoDeElementoHtml('elemSpan');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
);

function fun_cambiarIconoDeElementoHtml(arg_objOid){
    var varObj_html;
    varObj_html = document.getElementById(arg_objOid);
    alert(window.getComputedStyle(varObj_html, ':before').getPropertyValue('content'));
}
```

```css
#bloque_msj{display:none}
#elemSpan:before{
  content: 'X';
}
```

```html
<span id="elemSpan">Pinche aqui para desplegar</span>
<div id="bloque_msj">Lore Ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que de manera directa con javascript no se puede modificar el `:before`, no obstante hay otros métodos que son simples de implementar

#### 1) Usando clases

Agregas una clase que cambia el  `content`, luego con JS, colocas o quitas la clase

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => fun_cambiarIconoDeElementoHtml(e.target));

function fun_cambiarIconoDeElementoHtml(el){
   el.classList.toggle("conV");
}
```

```css
#bloque_msj{display:none}
#elemSpan:before{
  content: "X"
}
#elemSpan.conV:before{
  content: "V"
}
```

```html
<span id="elemSpan">Pinche aqui para desplegar</span>
<div id="bloque_msj">Lore Ipsum</div>
```

#### 2) Usando atributos

Agregas un atributo y el `content` lee aquel atributo con la función `attr()`

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => fun_cambiarIconoDeElementoHtml(e.target));

function fun_cambiarIconoDeElementoHtml(el){
   el.dataset.icono="V";
   
   //Toggle
   //el.dataset.icono=el.dataset.icono ==="X"?"V":"X";
}
```

```css
#bloque_msj{display:none}
#elemSpan:before{
  content: attr(data-icono)
}
```

```html
<span id="elemSpan" data-icono="X">Pinche aqui para desplegar</span>
<div id="bloque_msj">Lore Ipsum</div>
```

#### 3) Usando Propieddes

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => fun_cambiarIconoDeElementoHtml(e.target));

function fun_cambiarIconoDeElementoHtml(el){
   el.style.setProperty("--icono","'V'");
}
```

```css
@property --icono {
    syntax: "<string>";
    inherits: false;
    initial-value: "X";
}

#bloque_msj{display:none}

#elemSpan{
 --icono:"X";
}
#elemSpan:before{
  content: var(--icono);
}
```

```html
<span id="elemSpan">Pinche aqui para desplegar</span>
<div id="bloque_msj">Lore Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Yussef al final hice el cambio de clases y listo.